# How to select a newly added item in a databound combobox?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, data-binding, combobox

If I add an item to a databound combobox (by adding to the database and refreshing the TableAdapter), how can I then select the newly added item?

```
Private Sub button_Click(etc etc) etc
  Dim frm As New FormName()
  frm.ShowDialog()
  'On this form I add an entry to the database

  If frm.DialogResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
    'Refill TableAdapter
    'Now I want to select the new item!
    Combo.SelectedText = frm.TextBox.Text  'doesn't work - what's the best way to do this?
  End If
End Sub
```

It's not just the last index because the combobox items are sorted alphabetically, it could be anywhere in the list.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this code

```
ComboBox.Items.IndexOf(ComboBox.Items.Count - 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, this is a suggestion. What you could do is before you add the value to the database, have a variable to the value. When on postback (I believe we are talking about web applications), you do set the value inside the `IsPostBack` clause. There might be a better way for this to happen. But this is my first thought.

Comment: It's not a web application, just normal Windows forms.  Thanks anyway

Comment: alright. But i believe similar process logic could be adopted. I haven't worked with table adapters for a long while, but it should give your a success callback. When that event happens, set the ID that you saved earlier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding it to your database then rebinding the combobox, couldn't you just save the ID when you write it and then select the item that corresponds to the ID value?

Comment: That would be great but I don't know how to do that with the way I'm doing it, which is TableAdapter.Insert()

Comment: If it will be added as the last item in your table you could do a simple for loop and get the last id value for that table.  Or just have a stored procedure or function that returns the value of the last item added to your table.